# What is the best way to determine the supported styles of a font on iOS?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uifont

I'm unable to find an easy way to determine if a font supports the bold or italic font style on iOS. My current solution is based on trying to create a CTFont with the wished font style:

```
CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName(fontName, pointSize, NULL);
CTFontRef boldFont = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(ctFont, 0.0, NULL, kCTFontBoldTrait, kCTFontBoldTrait);
if (boldFont) {
// supports bold font face
}
```

While this works fine, it somehow doesn't feel like the best way to do it. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think so, UIFont is UIKits simple font class, the rest gets becomes very fast low level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use UIFont I guess you could just iterate the fontNamesForFamilyName:

```
for (NSString *fontName : [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:fontName]) {
    if ([fontName rangeOfString:@"Bold"].location != NSNotFound) {
       //supports bold font face
    }
}
```

Maybe not that much better... And a bold font isn't always defined with the text 'Bold', some use light and medium.
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6000-list-uifonts-available.html

Comment: This is also something I considered, however I think in this case I'd stick with my work around.

Comment: I stuck with my workaround described in the original question. However I'm marking this question as the best answer as it also mentions some things to keep in mind when looking for a bold font.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's hard to even figure out the family name, especially for custom fonts. Usually just print out all the fonts to check for available fonts. You can figure out all the styles e.g. Bold, italic, condensed bold etc, from this

```
NSArray *familyNames = [UIFont familyNames];
for (NSString *familyName in familyNames)
{
    NSSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName];
    NSLog(@"%@", fontNames);
}
```

Comment: I'm currently using a similar solution in my font picker, however I'm currently trying to mimic the style segmented control Apple is using in the iWork apps.